# Firebase realtime database returns all children instead of the single indicated one by OrderByKey().EqualTo(xxx)

Tags: firebase

I keep public profiles from my users like this:
[image: db schema]

Using the Unity SDK, I try to fetch a subset of the profiles with this query:

```cs
var profileDbRef = GetSharedDBInstance().RootReference.Child("profiles");
Query q = profileDbRef.OrderByKey();
userIds.ForEach(uId => q.EqualTo(uId));
q.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnSuccess(snapshot => {
    var profiles = (Dictionary<string, object>)snapshot.Value;
    // here profiles dictionary contains ALL my users, not the ones included in userIds list.
}
```

I receive all my users in the resulting snapshot. Not sure what's happening here? Is there a bug in the Unity SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `q.EqualTo(uId)` returns a new query object. So the fix was to change this one line to update the `q` variable.

```cs
userIds.ForEach(uId => q = q.EqualTo(uId));
```